# Was the rock the Moshe hit in Shemos 17 the be'er miriam

Tags: sources-mekorot, water, beshalach, chukas, dor-hamidbar

[Rashi in Bamidbar 20:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9948#showrashi=true&v=2) notes that until Miriam died the be'er [*literally* well] gave water.  Was this be'er the rock which Moshe hit in [Shemos 17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9878)? Or was it a well, and if so where is the first source for this in the Torah? Or is it just in Chazal?

Comment: cant find a source. But just went to a shiur tonight where the Rav touched upon this exact question. He said that the rock in Bamidbar was supposed to be rock from the be'er, but it somehow got switched with one that was a regular rock. This led to a pressure situation with Moshe. But alas the Rav at the shiur never mentioned a source.

Answer (score 2):

R. Shlomo Kluger [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38352&st=&pgnum=182&hilite=) commenting on verses 20:9 and 20:12 says that the rock was the Well of Miriam. Since Yisrael got this source of water in the merit of Miriam when she died it stopped producing water, but Hashem restored it in the merit of Moshe.